# Passing Typescript generics on React component through connect from react-redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-redux

I'm trying to use generics in a component that gets passed through react-redux's connect. Here's a stripped down version:

```
export default class ItemBar<T> extends React.PureComponent{
  // ...
}
```

When I use ItemBar with no connect, it looks like this:

```
export default class Component extends React.PureComponent {
   render() {
      return <ItemBar<number> />;
   }
}
```

This works properly. When I "connect" the ItemBar class as such:

```
class ItemBar<T> extends React.PureComponent {
  // ...
}

export default connect()(ItemBar);
```

I now get `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.` from Typescript. I think this is because the connect (and probably any other higher component) doesn't pass through the generics. Is there any way I can get this to work?

Comment: `export default connect()(ItemBar<T>);` what happens if you pass in generic to it.

Comment: This gives me a new error - `Value of type 'typeof ItemBar' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?`

Answer (score 0):

```
class ItemBar<T> extends React.PureComponent {
  // ...
}

const connected = connect()(ItemBar);

export class ItemBar<T> extends connected {}
```

You may have to disable tslint at last line if you have one class rule per file.